# Complicated SQL Statement: select that matches on multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have the tables:

- `Candidates`
- `CandidateLanguages`
- `CandidateSkills`

Each candidate may have more than 1 language and more than 1 skill

So for `Candidate` "FRED", his records in `CandidateLanguages` may be

```
FRED - ENGLISH
FRED - FRENCH
```

and his records in `CandidateSkills` may be

```
FRED - RUNNING
FRED - JUMPING
```

and for `Candidate` "JIM" his records in `CandidateLanguages` may be

```
JIM - ENGLISH
```

and his records in `CandidateSkills` may be

```
JIM - RUNNING
```

My query needs to select candidates that match multiple skills and languages.

So for example in English:

Select all of the candidates who speak ALL of the selected languages and have ALL of the selected skills...

Or put another way....

```
SELECT ALL candidates WHERE 
(language = 'FRENCH' AND language is 'ENGLISH') AND 
(skill = 'RUNNING' AND skill = 'JUMPING')
```

Of the two candidates above, this should only return "FRED"

I understand that the problem is with trying to select multiple records from the Language and Skills table and I think that joins may be required, but now I am lost...

Comment: Have you tried reversing the query? "give me all candidates that are missing one of the skills or missing one of the languages"? Sometimes rewording the problem can yield other/better solutions. If you stick a "not" in there in the right places it should give you the data you want, but the "not missing" part might be easier to formulate as a SQL query than the "having all" part.

Comment: thats 60 points.. 14 more and he reaches the daily limit, then he will have to wait for tomorrow..

Comment: @user1974729 : 6 upvotes in a question means 30 rep, not 60.

Comment: yups i know.. i just said 60 cos the multiplier looked so awesome.. i know it is 30..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are solving is called **Relational Division**.

See this article: **[Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)** and this question for a few ways to solve it: **[How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)**

One way to solve it (which will be - in general - the most efficient):

```
SELECT ALL c.candidate
FROM Candidates c
  JOIN CandidateLanguages lang1
    ON  lang1.candidate = c.candidate 
    AND lang1.language = 'English'
  JOIN CandidateLanguages lang2
    ON  lang2.candidate = c.candidate 
    AND lang2.language = 'French'
  JOIN CandidateSkills sk1
    ON  sk1.candidate = candidate 
    AND sk1.skill = 'Running'
  JOIN CandidateSkills sk2
    ON  sk2.candidate = candidate 
    AND sk2.skill = 'Jumping' ;
```

Another way, which seems easier to write, especially if there are a lot of languages and skills involved, is to use two derived tables with `GROUP BY` in each of them:

```
SELECT ALL c.candidate
FROM Candidates c
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT candidate
      FROM CandidateLanguages
      WHERE language IN ('English', 'French')
      GROUP BY candidate
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 2                     -- the number of languages
    ) AS lang
      ON  lang.candidate = c.candidate 
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT candidate
      FROM CandidateSkills 
      WHERE skill IN ('Running', 'Jumping')
      GROUP BY candidate
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 2                     -- the number of skills
    ) AS sk
      ON  sk.candidate = c.candidate ;
```

Comment: What if you have 15 languages and 60 skills?

Comment: @GaborSch Then you have 60+15 = 75 joins. I assure you that (in most cases) it will be much more efficient than `GROUP BY` queries.

Comment: Thank you ALL for your help and comments.  It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want *all skills* and *all languages*, simply counting the multiplications will be enough.

```
select c.id
from candidate c 
join candidateLanguage cl on c.id = cl.candidateId
join language l on cl.languageId = l.id
join candidateSkill cs on c.id = cd.candidateId
join skill s on s.id = cs.skillId
group by c.id
having count(*) = 4
```

The `having` condition can be expressed as

```
having count(*) = 
    (select count(*) from skill) * (select count(*) from language)
```

**What do I do here?**

- Listing all possible Candidate-Language-Skill triplets
- Grouping them by candidate
- if the count equals to (count of skills) * (count of languages) then for this candidate **all combinations are present**

**EDIT:**

If you only want a *subset* of languages and skills, you can filter it:

```
select c.id
from candidate c 
join candidateLanguage cl on c.id = cl.candidateId
join language l on cl.languageId = l.id
join candidateSkill cs on c.id = cd.candidateId
join skill s on s.id = cs.skillId
where l.name in ('English', 'French')
  and s.name in ('RUNNING', 'JUMPING')
group by c.id
having count(*) = 4
```

The difference here is that you can count only those skills and languages that are matching your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant, but efficient.

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  Candidates c
WHERE 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM   CandidateLanguages cl 
   WHERE  cl.candidateId = c.candidateId AND cl.language in ('FRENCH', 'ENGLISH')
  ) = 2
  AND
  (SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM   CandidateSkills cs 
   WHERE  cs.candidateId = c.candidateId AND cs.skill in ('RUNNING', 'JUMPING')
  ) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data query can be written as "Give me all candidates that have all the known skills that we have listed in a table, and all known languages we have listed in a different table", and not just "all the candidates with english and french, and both jumping and running", you can use one of these data-driven queries:

```
select
    *
from
    Candidates as C
where
    (select count(*) from CandidateLanguages where CandidateName = C.Name) = (select count(*) from Languages)
and (select count(*) from CandidateSkills where CandidateName = C.Name) = (select count(*) from Skills)
go

select
    *
from
    Candidates
where
    Name not in (
        select 
            C.Name
        from
            (Candidates as C cross join Languages as L)
            left join CandidateLanguages as CL on C.Name = CL.CandidateName and L.Name = CL.LanguageName
        where
            CL.CandidateName is null
    )
and Name not in (
        select
            C.Name
        from
            (Candidates as C cross join Skills as S)
            left join CandidateSkills as CS on C.Name = CS.CandidateName and S.Name = CS.LanguageName
        where
            CS.CandidateName is null
    )
go
```

Full example code that can be tested in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) is [available here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3w8g2g796bqixyl/SO17506444.linq). *(You may have to create the empty database)*

Answer (score -1):

```
 select candidate-name,resulttblskills1.sumCOLRATIOSKILLS,resulttbllanguages1.sumCOLRATIOLanguages from candidates candidates1

    join (select  count(*) as sumCOLRATIOskills
          from candidateskills skills1
          where skills1.requiredskills in ('jumping','canoeing','mostlygoofing'
          group by id
          ) as resulttblskills1 on resulttblskills1.id = candidates1.id 

    join (select  count(*) as sumCOLRATIOLANGUAGES
          from candidatelanguages languages1     
          where languages1.requiredlanguages in ('French','english','esparanto')
          group by id ) as resulttbllanguages1 on resulttbllanguages1.id = candidates1.id

    where resulttblskills1.sumCOLRATIOSKILLS > 1
          and resulttbllanguages1.sumCOLRATIOLANGUAGES > 1
```

Comment: Do you have `id` column on `resulttblskills1` and `resulttblskills2`?

Comment: ya well u r grouping by ID to get the sum for each id and joining the summed table on the primary keys..

Comment: I can't see it on the select line, probably you forgot to add it there. Also I think you want to correct the `sumCOLRATIOSKILLS > 1` condition as well.

Comment: well i just made up some columns there since i dont see the table design and mostly did not want to go with FK1=PK1 and FK2=PK2...
i think it is select from Maintable join (select sum from reqtable1) as sumreqtable1 on Foreign Key relationship join (select sum from reqtable2) as sumreqtable2 on Foreign Key Relationship where ur required sum conditions ...

Comment: Please stop using "txt spk". [(A relevant question on meta.)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105497)

Answer (score -2):

You are describing a many to many relationship between candidates and skills and also between candidates and languages.  Hopefully your database has the requisite tables.  The query would resemble this:

```
select yourfields
from candidate c join candidateLanguage cl on c.id = cl.candidateId
join languages l on cl.languageId = l.id
join candidateSkill cs on c.id = cd.candidateId
join skill s on s.id = cs.skillId
where l.language in ('FRENCH', 'ENGLISH')
and s.skill in ('RUNNING', 'JUMPING')
```

Comment: That query is not equivalent to the description, it'll return anyone speaking either language with either skill